# EditText problem:

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to show the text entered by the user in edittext other than from first space...
mean leaving a space in-front ....

Is that possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `android:paddingLeft` attribute if you only want a some space to be appeared to the user.

Comment: thanx for the answer...it worked..!! suppose if i want use the text entered by the user from edittext..then by using trim the original string will be retrieved right?..

Comment: This attribute makes nothing with your string, so you even don't have to trim it on retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Udaykiran,

I would accomplish this by attaching an [`onTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) listener and manually adding a buffer of spaces in front each time the user enters a new character.